# Needing create a Modal Dialog like UAC with a background screenshot

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, modal-dialog

Based in [this example](http://developex.com/blog/system-modal-back/) i'm wanting create a Modal Dialog Form inside new desktop created by `CreateDesktop` api. Until now i'm able to show Modal Dialog Form inside new desktop, but i don't know how create a background window with screenshot for also show inside new desktop together Modal Dialog Form.

So, someone can help me with this task?

Thank you to all.

**DlgMain.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScreenLockerDemo
{
    public partial class DlgMain : Form
    {
        public DlgMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lpszDevice, IntPtr pDevmode, int dwFlags, uint dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpsa);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool CloseDesktop(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetThreadDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetThreadDesktop(int dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

        enum DESKTOP_ACCESS : uint
        {
            DESKTOP_NONE = 0,
            DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001,
            DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x0002,
            DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x0004,
            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x0008,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x0010,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x0020,
            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x0040,
            DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080,
            DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100,

            GENERIC_ALL = (DESKTOP_READOBJECTS | DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW | DESKTOP_CREATEMENU |
                            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL | DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD | DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK |
                            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE | DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS | DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP),
        }



        private void buttonLockScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // old desktop's handle, obtained by getting the current desktop assigned for this thread
            IntPtr hOldDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

            // new desktop's handle, assigned automatically by CreateDesktop
            IntPtr hNewDesktop = CreateDesktop("RandomDesktopName", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, (uint)DESKTOP_ACCESS.GENERIC_ALL, IntPtr.Zero);

            // switching to the new desktop
            SwitchDesktop(hNewDesktop);     



            // running on a different thread, this way SetThreadDesktop won't fail
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                // assigning the new desktop to this thread - so the Modal Dialog Form will be shown in the new desktop)
                SetThreadDesktop(hNewDesktop);  

                Background Bkgfrm = new Background();
                Bkgfrm.Show();                                

                DlgLock DialogLock = new DlgLock();
                DialogLock.ShowDialog(Bkgfrm);


            }).Wait();  // waits for the task to finish
            // end of modal form

            // if got here, the form is closed => switch back to the old desktop
            SwitchDesktop(hOldDesktop);

            // disposing the secure desktop since it's no longer needed
            CloseDesktop(hNewDesktop);

        }
    }
}
```

**DlgLock.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScreenLockerDemo
{
    public partial class DlgLock : Form
    {
        public DlgLock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Background.cs**

```
namespace ScreenLockerDemo
{
    public partial class Background : Form
    {
        public Background()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void print(Bitmap BM, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphicsObj = e.Graphics;
            graphicsObj.DrawImage(BM, 60, 10);
            // graphicsObj.Dispose();
        }

        public void Background_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Background_Paint);
        }

        private void Background_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            int color = Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel;
            PixelFormat pf;
            pf = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
            Bitmap BM = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, pf);
       //   Bitmap BM = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\NZT48\Desktop\ScreenLockerDemo\bin\Debug\1.jpg"), rect.Width, rect.Height);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(BM);
            g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, rect.Size);
            Bitmap bitamp = new Bitmap(BM);
            print(bitamp, e);
        }

        private void Background_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Background_Paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No one? new desktop will have a background window that show a screenshot ( inside this window ) of old desktop. And Modal Dialog Form must be appear as son of background window.

Comment: I edited my code above. 
Now i want get screenshot of old desktop, but only is captured screen of new desktop.
So now, how get screenshot of old desktop and not of new desktop created?